# handler.postdelayed() milliseconds automatically changes after activity onResume()

Tags: android, android-handler

i'm using simple progressBar in my app with handler.postdelayed to change bar value (constant time) and initial bar value is 100.

```
Handler progress_handler;
Runnable runnable;
ProgressBar bar;
int progress;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bar= (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar();
}

private void progressBar()
{
    progress_handler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            progress=bar.getProgress();
            if(progress<=0)
            {
                progress_handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);

            }
            else {
                bar.setProgress(progress - 1);
                progress_handler.postDelayed(runnable, 50); // 50 milliseconds here 

            }
        }
    };
    // Start the Runnable immediately
    progress_handler.post(runnable);

}
```

this is working perfect but the problem happens when i pause and resume the activity

```
 @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    progress_handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    progress_handler.post(runnable);
}
```

now the progress bar speed is not 50 milliseconds as i set it is slower .. what happened ?

Comment: Do you want your value to keep changing, or only change once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your progress to keep decreasing, you need to use a `Timer` instead of a `Handler`

```
Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)
```

Where `task` is basically your `Runnable`

You can create everything in `onCreate`, and in the activity's `onResume()` call `scheduleAtFixedRate` and call `cancel` in `onPause`

However, this runs your code on a background thread, so you man need a Handler to `post` data on UI thread, or use `runOnUiThread` of the activity.

Another option would be using Android's [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

A third option would be to remove extra call to handler.post in onCreate, only keep one in onResume

Comment: thank you for your answer ..but why this is not working ?
i'm using "progress_handler.postDelayed(runnable, 50);" in Runnable's run() method.
i will try using Timer option after i make  sure that is Runnable can't do what i want

Comment: PostDelayed will make you code run once after the specified delay, which I guess is not what you want

Comment: PostDelayed will be called every time while  Progress > 0
and that is what happening here but the problem is the delay time ...delay time changes after switching activities(although PostDelayed is called too).

Comment: Apologies for mis-reading your original code, I see now that you are re-posting it inside your runnable, however you are calling post() twice, once in your onCreate and once in your onResume, which both are going to be called when your activity is created at the very first time to appear. Try removing the once in onCreate() and only keep the one in onResume(). Also add a log in the "else" of your condition and see how "often" is it called using the log timestamp.

Comment: THANK YOU <3 
now it is working ... the problem as you said that i'm  calling handler.post() twice 
it is working as expected now after removing handler.post(runnable); in progressBar() function.
maybe you should edit your third method in your answer so i can accept your answer.

Comment: Done! Glad I could help